# matplotlib tricontourf with an axis projection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to contour irregularly sampled data on a sphere, but tricontourf is not behaving well.

example of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Generate some random data points
ra = np.random.rand(100)*np.pi*2-np.pi
dec = np.random.rand(100)*np.pi-np.pi/2.
z = np.sin(ra)+np.cos(dec)

levels=100
# Contour the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
TF = ax.tricontourf(ra,dec,z, levels)
fig.savefig('noproject.png')
# Contour with an aitoff projection
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='aitoff')
TF = ax.tricontourf(ra,dec,z, levels)
fig.savefig('aitoff.png')
```

[image: noproject.png]
[image: aitoff.png]

I can do it with mpl_toolkits.basemap, but I'd like to avoid the dependency since it seems like this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proof it works with basemap

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ra = np.random.rand(100)*np.pi*2-np.pi
dec = np.random.rand(100)*np.pi-np.pi/2.
z = np.sin(ra)+np.cos(dec)
levels=100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
m = Basemap(projection='nplaea', boundinglat=20., lon_0=0., resolution='l')
MC = m.contourf(np.degrees(ra),np.degrees(dec),
                z, levels, ax=ax, tri=True, latlon=True)
m.drawparallels(np.arange(0,81,20))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,181,60))
fig.savefig('baseContour.png')
```

[image]